# Iterate over Generator which returns a Generator

Tags: javascript, loops, generator

I try to understand Generators, but I found an example which I can not follow.

```js
// First Generator

function* Colors ()
{
  yield "blue";
  yield* MoreColors ();
  yield "green";
 }

// Generator refered by the first Generator
function* MoreColors ()
{
  yield "yellow";
  yield "orange";
 }


// Let us iterate over the first Generator

const colorIterator = Colors();

let color;

while (!(color = colorIterator.next()).done)
{
  console.log(color.value);
}
```

**The output is:**
"blue"
"yellow"
"orange"
"green"

**I expected:**
"blue"
"yellow"
"orange"

**Why I expected this:**
I think that after *orange* has been returned, the method *.next()* is called on the Iterator from *MoreColors ()*. This should return an object with the propery value *true* for the property *.done*.
By this, *item* is equals *true* and the while-loop should stop.

Obviously, my expectations are wrong.

I would be glad, if someone could point out what I get wrong.

Comment: `yield*` would be pretty useless if it didn't fixup `done` attributes; it would mean the outer generator reports being done as soon as the first delegated generator finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the generator Colors does not stop once MoreColors stops. After MoreColors is done, the execution of Colors continues from where it stopped, and so it would return "green" before being done. That's because the generator does not "become" MoreColors, but rather returns its answers, and the .next() method is still called on Colors.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! But technically I still do not understand what is happening. Do I understand your answer correctly, that the generator Colors is responsible by itself, that the while-loop is further executed?

Comment: Yes. When you use yield*, and the generator you apply it on (MoreColors) returns {done: true}, the original generator (Colors) detects that and instead of returning that value, continues its execution until it reaches another yield statement or completes its execution

Comment: matanso and @ShadowRanger: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge! You helped me a lot!